# '0' In Routing path is causing NoReverseMatch error

Tags: django

I have the following URL route defined:

```
url(
    regex=r'^edit_meal/(?P<menu_item_id>\d+)/(?P<parent_item_id>\d+)/$',
    view=EditMealView.as_view(),
    name='edit_meal',
)
```

When I pass the following URL, it gets the error posted just below it:

```
http://localhost:8000/menu_manager/edit_meal/0/5/

Reverse for 'edit_meal' with arguments '(0,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['menu_manager/edit_meal/(?P<menu_item_id>\\d+)/(?P<parent_item_id>\\d+)/$']
```

However, if I change the '/0/5/' to '/1/5/' (or any number other than '0'), it works fine.

Also, if I use '/1/0/', there is no issue.

How can I get the router to accept '0' in the first argument?

Tag in template:

```
{% url 'menu_manager:edit_meal' 0 menu.id %}
```

Comment: Can you show the `{% url ... %}` in that template? It looks like you use an `{% url 'edit_meal' ... %}` but with only *one* parameter.

Comment: Is there a `menu` in you context variables?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem updated, thanks. {% url 'menu_manager:edit_meal' 0 menu.id %}

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Not sure what you're getting at. As I mentioned, the issue is only arising when there is a '0' in the first position. The URL I posted above is generated by this tag. So the link is being properly created.

Comment: usually an `id=0` does not exists, so perhaps `menu` is `None`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I believe you are looking in the wrong spot. The issue is the routing properly handling the URL it is fed. Everything works fine if the '0' is changed to any other number.

Comment: no, that happens fine. Otherwise you would get a 404, not an error message. The error is `Reverse for 'edit_meal' with arguments '(0,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) `, so that means it aims to perform a reverse lookup when *executing* the corresponding view. As you can see, one of the parameters is missing. If you enter a wrong URL, you do *not* get a "paths tried" error.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for the response. However, the error is not taking place while rendering the view that has this tag. It happens even if I just paste the URL I mentioned above into my browser and hit Enter. The issue is happening somewhere during routing. If I change the '0' to '1', it works perfectly.

Comment: Likely you use `.first()` somewhere, and hence the `Meal` is `None`, not a `Meal` object, and thus somehow "altering" the behavior.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You are correct. I didn't realize the error was coming from another view. Thanks.